# The limit of this sequence $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^{3}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $$u_n =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^{3}}$$
I have to calculate the following limit :
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} u_n$$
I first evaluated the sum :
$$\begin{aligned} u_{n} &=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^{3}} \\ &=\frac{1}{n^{3}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \\ &=\frac{1}{n^{3}} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\ &=\frac{n+1}{2 n^{2}} \\ \lim_{n \rightarrow+\infty} & u_{n}=0 \end{aligned}$$
The only problem I'm facing is that there's no $0$ in the answers, I have 4 answers which are :
$$ 1 \ \ \frac{1}{e} \ \ \frac{1}{3} \ \ \frac{1}{6}$$
Where's my mistake ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: The given answers are wrong and your answer is right.

Comment: Yes. As stated, the answer is $0$, and your solution is correct. Are you certain of the question?

Comment: I suspect there is a typo in your question. If $u_n$ is $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^{\color{red}{2}}}{n^3}$, then the answer is $\frac13$.